# self.navigationController is null after it is assign as RootViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I created a new xcode project as View-based application, and I have a set of `UIViewController`(s) which I plan to use inside separate `UINavigationController`(s).

In `ParentViewController.m` before all the `UINavigationController`(s) and after all myViewControllers been initiated:

```
NSMutableArray *navControllers = [[NSMutableArray array];
for (id aVC in self.myViewControllers) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aVC];

    //[aVC setNavigationController:navController];
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [navController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [navControllers addObject:navController];
    [navController release];
}

_navigationControllers = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:navigationControllers] retain];
```

`_navigationControllers` is retained as a member of `ParentViewController`, so I suppose all my navigation controllers initiated inside for-loop are kept by `_navigationControllers` so they won't be released or become `nil`, but when I try to use navigationController in `MyViewController` to push `SomeOtherViewController`, it  doesn't work:

```
- (IBAction)pushDetailView {
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I put a breakpoint before `pushViewController:someOtherViewController`, and "po [self navigationController]",  the console tells me it is a `nil` reference.

I assumed that when I do 
`[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aVC]`, the underlying mechanism would assign the `navigationController` as `aVC.navigationController`, because the Apple "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" does the same without assigning `navigationController` to `rootController`.

Unless I unmark the second line of the for-loop `//[aVC setNavigationController:navController];`, the `navigationController` does not exist in aVC.

Am I misunderstanding the mechanism? Is there another solution for my case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the property declaration for _navigationControllers from the parent.h file.  All your assumptions/logic in the question seem ok to me (i.e. initWithRootViewController should set the navigationController property on the root view controller automatically)

Answer (score -1):

```
_navigationControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id aVC in self.myViewControllers) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aVC];

    //[aVC setNavigationController:navController];
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [navController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [navControllers addObject:navController];
}

// assuming index 0 navigation controller is with 'ParentViewController'
self.rootViewController = [_navigationControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

check with this.